# Wordpress Get value of hidden input field in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a hidden input field, which I want to fetch in my `functions.php`, but I keep getting  `NULL` as a return value.

Here is my code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_field_data_to_cart', 10, 2 );

function add_custom_field_data_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    $cart_item_data['myHiddenInput'] = $_POST['myHiddenInput']; 
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Can someone maybe tell me why I get `NULL` ?

**EDIT**

The hidden input field is on my `archive-products.php` of my `woocommerce`-shop

```
<input type="hidden" name="myHiddenInput" value="">
```

The value gets set by using `javascript`

**UPDATE**

What I want to achive is, that I have an archive-products page where all my products are listed. Now, above my products I have a tab-menu with the next 5 days of the week. So I click the tab "Wednesday 19." the value of the hidden input gets the date of the active menu-tab:

```
<input type="hidden" name="chosenDate" value="2018-09-19">
```

Now I add a product to my cart. Then I click the menu-tab "Friday 21." - the value of the hidden filed gets updated -> I add a product to the cart.

Now when I go to my cart page - I want the products to have the dates listed when they will get delivered (the dates from the menu-tab when they were added)

Comment: Where do you have the input hidden field?

Comment: hidden input is an html option, you need to post the html code

Comment: @KrishnaJoshi Please check my updated question...

Comment: have you tried to kill the function to debug it?

Comment: Something like `var_dump($_POST); wp_die();` should let you be able to see it?

Comment: @Stender Unfotunately I don't see anything

Comment: Is your filter being added? try `add_action( 'all', create_function( '', 'var_dump( current_filter() );' ) );` this should show you alle the filters that are loaded - do your action and see if it is presented.

Comment: also - the `var_dump()` and `wp_die()` was before the return, right?

Comment: @Stender actually it turns out, that the filter is not added :o !! Why? and How can I add it?

Comment: based on this logic you are posting you will not be able to get those hidden filed value, as add to cart is handled by WooCommerce JavaScript which take the attribute from the button as value and stored in the session, so if you explain what exactly you want to achieve, you might get better help from me or form someone else

Comment: @kashalo please see my updated question

Comment: You can't pass anything custom from any archive page via ajax add to cart button as if you look to the source code of [Ajax add to cart](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_AJAX.html#356-397)… There is no possible additional arguments or hooks. So you will need to build your own Ajax add to cart functionality, which is something huge and complicated. So your hooked function `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` will have no effect.

Comment: @ST80 check the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @LoicTheAztec Said

> You can't pass anything custom from any archive page via ajax add to cart button as if you look to the source code of Ajax add to cart… There is no possible additional arguments or hooks. So you will need to build your own Ajax add to cart functionality, which is something huge and complicated. So your hooked function woocommerce_add_cart_item_data will have no effect

so the best logic is to use Javascript to achieve your goal and you can do it like the below solution:

**First** Lets add those value inside the add to cart button as an attribute instead of `input` tag.

for that we are going to us `woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args` hook as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'change_item_price', 10, 2 );
function change_item_price( $args, $product ) {
    $args['attributes'] = $args['attributes'] + [ 'data-chosen-date' => '2018-09-19' ];

    return $args;
}
```

you can add as many attribute as you want and modify the value through your script and then store those value when the user click add to cart intro session storage  and then in the cart page you can get those values and append them to cart table so for example:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'script' );
function script() {

    if ( is_shop() ) {?>
    <script>
    document.body.addEventListener('click', add_to_cart);
    function add_to_cart(e) {
        if (e.target.classList.contains('add_to_cart_button')) {
            let val = e.target.getAttribute('data-chosen-date');
            let product_id = e.target.getAttribute('data-product_id');
            sessionStorage.setItem(product_id, val);
        }
    }
    </script>
        <?php

    }
    if ( is_cart() ) {
        ?>
        <script>
        var items = document.querySelectorAll("td");
        items.forEach(function (item, index) {

        if (item.classList.contains('product-remove')) {
        var id = item.childNodes[1].getAttribute('data-product_id');
        if (sessionStorage.getItem(id)) {

            var textnode = document.createElement('p');
            textnode.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem(id);
            item.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.appendChild(textnode)

            }
        }
        }); </script>
        <?php
    }

}
```

**output :**

[image]

The **Date**  after the item link in the cart table has been retrieved from our storage session and each value we stored is maped with the product id as key in our storage session so we can have different value for each product.

Comment: Thats actually pretty decent! :-) What about if I update the amount of items e.g. update the cart? then the date is not showing anymore...

Comment: @ST80  you can add an event listener if you updated the item then you can re append this date the date is already saved in user sessions so basically you can do whatever u want

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot :-)

Comment: Just a quick question @kashalo : when I add a product on for example the 2018-09-19 and the same product on the next day, the cart displays that product only once with an amount of two. Can I avoid that? I want the product to be displayed for the each day it was ordered

Comment: @ST80 no by default that's not possible, you have to override the whole add to cart process for this on, it's different logic than the default one

Comment: Ok crap :-/ Thanks for the effort anyways @kashalo! :-)

Comment: When I order the same product for two different days, the date displayed on both products is always the latest one... Do you maybe have a solution for that? @kashalo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180426/discussion-between-kashalo-and-st80).